# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Build failure with BlackBerry 10

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-10

I am trying to follow the steps in [Creating an IBM Worklight BlackBerry 10 environment](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_creating_a_new_ibm_BlackBerry_10_environment.html).
But while running this command (`ant qnx copy-extension`) it is throwing error given below

```
D:\f\f\proj1\apps\proj1\blackberry10\nat
ive>ant qnx copy-extension
Buildfile: D:\f\f\proj1\apps\proj1\black
berry10\native\build.xml

qnx:

BUILD FAILED
Target "copy-extension" does not exist in the project "Build and Deploy a Cordov
a BlackBerry WebWorks Project".

Total time: 0 seconds
```

I have also tried these steps mentioned [in this article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/worklight_blackberry10_project_with_webworks_sdk_2_0?lang=en) but it is throwing `cardova initilize failed`.

Sample Project:

- [Blackbery 10 Sample project on worklight 6.1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68580104/BB10S.zip)

Comment: Worklight does not officially yet support WebWorks sdk 2... Try again with WebWorks SDK 1 and see if the error persists.

Comment: I have already tried for both (SDK1, SDK2 )but not workings.

Comment: What are you doing in your application? Does a new app work? When does it fail? What do you add to your application?

Comment: Nothing extra i am adding , even a new app is not working at lauch it is throwing `cardova not initialized`

Comment: @IdanAdar : i have just shared the sample project , please check and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using an non-existing command.
Try the below and see if it resolves this specific build failure:

In your command line, replace:

```
ant qnx copy-extension
```

With:

```
ant qnx copy-extensions
```

From the [user documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_creating_a_new_ibm_BlackBerry_10_environment.html):

> c. In the {project name}/apps/{app name}/blackberry10/native folder,
>   run the **ant qnx copy-extensions** command.

Comment: Now this command is working but app launch is still saying `Cardova initilize failed`